# Dagger: Third-party classes can't be annotated?

Tags: android, dagger

I am new to Dagger. In its [doc](http://square.github.io/dagger/), it's said

> Third-party classes can't be annotated

But in this [UpcomingMoviesMVP](https://github.com/jlmd/UpcomingMoviesMVP) sample, it injects the OTTO bus in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Inject
protected Bus bus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerBus();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unRegisterBus();
}

private void registerBus() {
    bus.register(this);
}

private void unRegisterBus() {
    bus.unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void onItemSelectedEvent(MovieSelectedEvent event) {
    launchMovieDetailsActivity(event.getMovie());
}
```

So I think Dagger should invoke the default constructor of the Bus (Of course, there is no inject annotation in Bus constructor). But it seems conflicting with "Third-party classes can't be annotated"?

Comment: Do you get an error when you do this?

Comment: No, it could compile and run successfully in the android studio. Working perfectly.....

Comment: I think what is meant that you cannot annotate the constructor of a third party class (since you can't modify the source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think Dagger should invoke the default constructor of the Bus

What if there are multiple constructors? Which does it choose?

Dagger will not randomly create class instances. You have to tell it which to use or create it yourself.

In this case, `Bus` could be annotated with an `@Inject` constructor. This would allow Dagger to inject it without anything else. Otto does not have this, however, so it must be coming from somewhere else.

The other way is to write a provider method.

```
@Provides @Singleton Bus provideBus() {
  return new Bus();
}
```

This method (written in a Dagger `@Module`) will provide Dagger a means of obtaining a `Bus` instance to inject. And since it's annotated with `@Singleton`, Dagger will only call this method once and re-use the instance over and over again each time it is requested.